# I cannot exit when I go into the loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

```
import java.util.*;

public class ConvertBinaryToInteger{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    final String EXIT="exit";


    System.out.println("This program will convert a binary into an integer.");
    System.out.println("Enter "+EXIT+" to exit program. Press enter to continue.");
    String word=scan.nextLine();

    while(!word.equals(EXIT)){

            while(!word.equals(EXIT)){
                boolean valid = false;
                while (!valid) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
                    String binary = scan.next();
                    boolean isBinary = true;//first convert the 'binary' string into a char array and check for each char whether it is zero or one
                    char[] bits = binary.toCharArray();

                    for(int j=0; j<bits.length; j++){//read the inputs

                        if( (bits[j] != '0') && (bits[j] != '1') ){//check the inputs
                            isBinary = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!isBinary){//not binary
                        System.out.println("This is not a binary number.");
                        System.out.println("Please enter a number that contains only 1's and 0's.");
                        System.out.println("Enter "+EXIT+" to exit program. Press enter to continue.");
                        word=scan.nextLine();
                    }
                    else{//binary
                        int integer = 0;
                        int temp;
                        int i = 0;
                        temp = Integer.parseInt(binary);

                        while (temp != 0){
                            int r = temp % 10;
                            double value = r * Math.pow(2, i);
                            i++;
                            integer = (int) (integer + value);
                            temp /= 10;
                        }
                        System.out.println("Integer of " + binary + " is " + integer+".");
                        System.out.println("Enter "+EXIT+" to exit program. Press enter to continue.");
                        word=scan.nextLine();
                    }   
                    System.out.println();
                    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                }


            }



        }System.out.println("Program ended.");
    }

}
```

cannot exit after entered a correct binary. Please help me to change the program... 
if you didn't exit in the first place, you cannot end the program..

Comment: Not sure what those nested while loops are about.

Comment: Please state your question in addition to showing code.

Comment: Trim your code to have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (!valid) {
```

`valid` is never updated. If they want to exit, set `valid` to `true` as well as updating the value of `word`.

As pointed out by `@AnthonyGrist`, removing the `while(!valid)` loop altogether will also fix this issue.

Comment: That `while(!valid)` loop looks completely unnecessary, so removing it entirely would also fix the issue.

Comment: It would, but given OP made a minimal amount of effort, I don't much feel like redesigning their code for them.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this code](http://pastie.org/private/pr0rdxkoj1rzy9mbvksja) 
it is up and running

PS: removing the !valid condition will also not lead to termination of the program on entering exit. i tried it.

The issue is you are displaying the message and also writing scan.nextline() immediately, which accepts a blank, this is neither = to exit and also valid whether set to true or not, will always be initialized to false, as it enters the word.equals(..  condition.